# Trying to solve 2 equations with 2 unknowns symbolically using MATLAB

Tags: matlab

Trying to solve 2 equations with 2 unknown using MATLAB and it is not liking my input.

Where c is 3.06 + 2.57j, and v is 12:

```
eq1 = 'c = a/10j'
eq2 = '(6b)/50 + b/10j = a/10j + a/10'
```

Trying to solve for a and b. Any suggestions of how to properly put these in?

Answer (score 2):

Matlab is screwed up, but the syntax is

```
sol = solve(eq1,x1,eq2,x2,..);
```

It would make more sense to make it `solve({eq1,eq2,..},{x1,x2,..})` but no, we have to write out all the arguments one by one.

Anyway the trick is that eq1, eq2, .. are symbolic expressions that must be evaluated to zero. So instead of `c = a/10j` it needs to be `eq1=sym('c-a/10j')`

So try this:

```
eq1 = sym('c - a/(10*i)');   % must evaluate to zero
eq2 = sym('(6*b)/50 + b/(10*i) -( a/(10*i) + a/10)'); %must evaluate to zero

sol = solve(eq1,'a',eq2,'b');

a = subs(sol.a,'c',3.06+2.57j)
b = subs(sol.b,'c',3.06+2.57j)
```

produces `a= -25.7000 +30.6000i` and `b=-20.6639 +29.6967i`.

Note that symbolic functions do not understand `10j`. It needs to be `10*i`. Also the notatation `6b` is missing an operator and needs to be `6*b`.

Good luck!

---

Since the problem is linear there is another way to solve it

```
equs = [eq1;eq2];
vars = [sym('a');sym('b')];
A = jacobian(equs,vars);
b = A*vars - equs;

x = A\b;
c = 3.06+2.57j;
sol = subs(x,'c',c)
```

with results

```
sol =
 -25.7000 +30.6000i
 -20.6639 +29.6967i
```

Comment: omg, it's that easy, you just put your homework on stackoverflow and people will give you the answer with comments on the plate

Comment: Your complaint about the syntax of [SOLVE](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/symbolic/solve.html) doesn't make sense. You can call it like so: `sol = solve(eq1,eq2,'a','b');`. Are you using an older version of MATLAB?

Comment: I am complaining because MATLAB needs to follow suit from mupad and make it `sol = solve(equs,vars)` where `equs` is a vector of expressions and `vars` a vector of variables. Even if they are cell vectors. How would you write a solve statement now if you have variable number of euquations (and variables) to solve for in a problem?

Comment: You can easily do that with cell arrays: `equs = {eq1,eq2}; vars = {'a','b'}; sol = solve(equs{:},vars{:});`

Answer (score 0):

you need to tell matlab that c,eq1,eq2,a,j (is this not complex?), and b are a symbolic variables. i.e. use the command "syms a b c j eq1 eq2". Then define everything as you have done above minus your single quotes (that's a string!).

then you can just use the 'solve(eq2,'variable you want to solve for'). Easy enough.